# Linking to a specific section on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I am wondering if this is possible and if so, how I would do it.

I have a page called services with different services all listed within it. The thing is, all of those services are hidden on page load and only show if a tab is clicked. To see this, click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k0vrcsrh/3/).

Let's say I have a footer with services listed in the footer. Like this:

Service 1

Service 2

Service 3

If someone clicks on service two, I am wanting the link to take them to my services page and to show the services two section on page load, while still hiding all of the other services.

This is the javascript to show/hide my different services.

```
$('.service-tab-block').click(function() {
    $('.service-tab-block').css({"background":"purple" , "color" : "#000"});
    $(this).css({"background":"#000", "color":"#FFF"});

    //To get the service display box to show
    var item_number = $(this).attr('id').replace('service_tab', '');
    $('#service-display-box').show();
     $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#service-display-box").offset().top
  }, 1500);
    $('#service'+item_number).show().siblings().hide();
    $('#service-top').show();
})
```

So, is it possible to click on a link and be taken to my page and show a specific service and the div it is in (at the top of the page)?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but since you are going to a new page you would be better off using a server side language

Comment: Your jsFiddle doesn't have any html in it.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I am unsure of what to search to even figure out how to do this. What would the technical name for this be?